# Angular passing dropdown value instead of actual string to Node

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I have a dropdown that is populated based off a jSON object I have created. I am trying to pass the text value "wineSupplier" to be the text selection in the dropdown, but instead it is passing the array value in the POST to Node.

Thus, if my dropdown has the following options:

- A
- B
- C
- D

  and I choose "C" the value of 2 is being passed, I would like to be able to receive "C"

Code Snippet from wines.ejs:

```
            <form action="/createWine" method="POST">
                <p>Select the Wine Supplier:</p>
                <select name="wineSupplier" ng-model="supplierSelection" ng-options="supplier as supplier.supName for supplier in suppliers">
                </select>
                <label>Wine Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="wineName" placeholder="Wine Name"/>
                <label>Wine Producer:</label>
                <input type="text" name="wineProducer" placeholder="Wine Producer"/>
                <label>Wine Colour:</label>
                <input type="text" name="wineColour" placeholder="Wine Colour"/>
                <label>Wine Type:</label>
                <input type="text" name="wineType" placeholder="Wine Type"/>
                <label>Wine Country:</label>
                <input type="text" name="wineCountry" placeholder="Wine Country"/>
                <p>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
                </p>
            </form>
```

Code Snipper from app.js

```
//Create a new wine objhect

app.post('/createWine', function(request, response) {
    //create and save a wine model
    var wine = new myWine({
        wineSupplier: request.body.wineSupplier,
        wineName: request.body.wineName,
        wineProducer: request.body.wineProducer,
        wineColour: request.body.wineColour,
        wineType: request.body.wineType,
        wineCountry: request.body.wineCountry
    });

    //save to model
    wine.save(function(err, model) {
        if (err) {
            response.send(504, 'There was an error');
        }
        else {
            response.redirect('/');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It looks ok at first glance.  What does a `supplier` look like?

Comment: ng-options="supplier.supName as supplier.supName for supplier in suppliers

Comment: Its because your value is set to array supplier as per your code.So selecting C is the index 2 of that array.That's why. Change the as as mentioned above.

Comment: @AlaksandarJesusGene I think the current one is ok.  That binds to the actual element there.  Not the index.  I think there problem is how the actual `supplier` is getting treated, or what it is.

Comment: Okay so changed to "ng-options="supplier.supName as supplier.supName for supplier in suppliers">" and still getting the array value.

Comment: This JS fiddle will help you to code select                                                             http://jsfiddle.net/alaksandarjesus/gqevvvne/

Answer (score 2):

When you want the actual value of the `<option>`s and the `<select>` itself to be a value from your model, you should use `track by`.

Without `track by`, AngularJS will give the `<options>` numerical values that it will use to keep track of which selections belong to which array items.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('C', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.suppliers = [{supName:'A'},{supName:'B'}, {supName:'C'}, {supName:'D'}];
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="C">
  <select name="wineSupplier" ng-model="supplierSelection" 
          ng-options="supplier.supName for supplier in suppliers track by supplier.supName">
  </select>
</div>
```

On the other hand, it seems like you are somewhat misusing Angular by using it to just provide part of your form and using a plain submit to submit the values. Ideally, all of your controls should be bound to fields in the model, and you should use AngularJS to perform the submit to the server. If you do this, you won't need to use `track by`.

Comment: That works! Thank you sooooo much, saved a newbie from hours upon hours of headaches.